# Spectral Clustering in Resting-State fMRI

Tags: neural-networks, clustering, matlab, spectral-analysis

I have 200 .hdr/.img file pairs for person in which the carried out pre-processing using SPM. I want to apply spectral clustering for voxel time courses to find resting state networks. 
How can I extract voxel time courses from fMRI time series of .hdr/.img file in MatLab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SPM functions to do that.
(http://www.fil.ion.ucl.ac.uk/spm/software/)

% Pop up window for file selection (you can select to read in multiple images at the same time)

fNames = spm_select(Inf, 'image');

% Get header information

V = spm_vol(fNames);

% Read the actual images

X = spm_read_vols(V);

Comment: I received information about the file: dim [79 95 78], mat[4x4 double], pinfo [2,25225877761841;0;0], dt [4 0], n[1 1]. But I don't undestand how to get temporal dependence. How to get bold signal for each voxel?               Once again, thanks for your attention and your valuable time!

Comment: Information about the file is in the structure V. The actual bold signals are in the array X